# How write in html text input by using php

Tags: php, html, input

I have this html text input:

```
<input type="text" id='message'>
```

And I want to write this php variable into the text input:

```
$command="time={$_POST["time"]}age={$_POST["age"]}name={$_POST["name"]}";
```

I prefer the php file to write the value into the textbox, not the html to get it from the php file.How can I possibly do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`value`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp) attribute of `input` tag:

```
<input type="text" id="message" value="<?php echo $command;?>"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i prefer the php file to write the value in to the textbox, not the textbox to get the value from the php file...Sorry that i didn't mention that in the question.

Comment: What do you mean `php file to write the value in to the textbox`? How could you possibly achieve that? `PHP` cannot dynamically interact with the `DOM` once the page loaded. You might be looking for `javascript`/`jQuery` here.